# Problem with Beam Splitter Refraction

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, non-linear-optics

I made a beam splitter for a simple test, as shown in the images below:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/azt9U8L.jpg]

[image]

This was my expected ray trace:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ra1qo8j.jpg]

But it instead refracted light like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/pyiic89.jpg]

Why did the splitter cause light to refract in this manner?  What was wrong with my original prediction?

Specs for the splitter:

> material: BK7
>
> slope surface coating, 50:50, 30:70

---

## additional info

ray tracing simulation image 2 (split ray option 'ON') :
[image]

real ray tracing(no B/S) :
[image]

real ray tracing(B/S right surface) :
[image]

real ray tracing(B/S left surface) :
[image]

Comment: Your ray trace seems to not take into account the reflections at the interface (i.e. the beamsplitter).  Did you set their reflectivity properly?

Comment: There is no, or minimal, **refraction**. You're seeing the translated beams due to **reflection** at the various interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Your ray tracing is not quite complete. Part of the beam reflected off the upper splitter will be reflected again by the lower one, thus producing two images spatially separated.

Also the surfaces of the BS seem curved, so we will have some lensing, probably explaining the magnification observed on the image.